# Relationship between Bijections and Cardinality

Tags: functions, cardinals

Can a function $f:A\to A$ be onto but not injective? My thought process would be that if it is onto, then the $range(f)$ would be $A$. Then wouldn't it follow that the function is one-to-one, since $|dom(f)| = |range(f)|$.

Comment: When $A$ is finite then $f:A\to A$ being onto does imply that it is also one-to-one.  This fails when $A$ is not finite.  As two examples, consider $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ given by $f(n)=2n$ which is one-to-one but not onto since for example there is no $n$ such that $f(n)=3$, and consider $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ which is onto but not one-to-one since for example $f(2)=f(3)=1$

Comment: @JMoravitz That's more like an answer than a comment...